# Extracting secret key - d of RSA

Tags: algorithms, cryptography

I need to prove that if John can ask Alice to sign any messages, John will eventually figure out secret key "d" and decrypt all Alice's messages. How do I go about proving that. Any hint will be appreciated.

What is known - public key (N,e),

Signature((N,e),msg) => msg^d (mod N)

One approach I'm thinking is find d from the definition of "e*d congruent 1 mod N".

Comment: iirc $ed \equiv 1 \mod n$ is not how RSA works, rather $\mod \varphi(n)$

Comment: ok. But is there a way to extract "d" from different messages if John can ask Alice to sign any messages?

Comment: I don't think that there is a way which is significantly faster than factorizing $n$, but i am really no expert on RSA

Comment: The first thought that hit me was to get her to sign the message $2$.  Now you have $2^d \pmod {N}$  Does that help?

Comment: Could you explain why you pick 2?

Comment: I think one usually would sign a hash of the message. Is this step included in your algorithm?

Comment: @Thomas Nope. I was given function prototype of Signature function.

Comment: There are some confusions here. You say that Alice will **sign** any message that John sends her. Well, if that is the case, and you are doing **signing** as $m^d\bmod{n}$, then John can give her any ciphertext $c$ encrypted as $c=m^e\bmod{n}$ and she will "sign" it, giving John $m$. So in that sense, John can get Alice to decrypt anything for him.

Answer (score 0):

Asking Alice to sign something arbitrarily is equivalent to a
[Chosen Ciphertext Attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chosen-ciphertext_attack)
because you signing is the same operation as decrypting ( $ m^d \mod n$).
How save is that for RSA? that is discussed here:
[CC-Attack for RSA](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/9452/is-a-private-rsa-key-vulnerable-to-a-chosen-plaintext-encrypted-with-that-privat)

Summary: you cannot get the $d$ directly (or there is no known fast way), so the answer to your original question would be "no". However, it could be used to decrypt any given Message (even without Alice noticing it).

Other links that explain that:
[here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/2323/how-does-a-chosen-plaintext-attack-on-rsa-work) and [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/18631/chosen-plaintext-attack-on-textbook-rsa-decryption)